# How to control which ethernet interface Windows selects when resolving fully-qualified domain machine names?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I have a VM in AWS. I has two ethernet interfaces, which have different security groups applied to them. One of those security groups white-lists all sorts of machine addresses in my domain. When resolving the machine's fully-qualified domain name, I want the interface with the domain-friendly security to be resolved, however at present it's the other interface that's being resolved.

When enumerating the ethernet interfaces using `netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces`, the unfriendly interface happens to be listed first in order of Idx:

```
Idx     Met         MTU          State                Name
---  ----------  ----------  ------------  ---------------------------
  1          50  4294967295  connected     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1
 13          20        1500  connected     Local Area Connection 2
 15          20        1500  connected     Local Area Connection 1
```

Based on the absence of better information, I might guess that Windows is just picking the first ipv4 interface it finds in this list when being asked to resolve the machine name. Is this the case? If so, is it possible to reorder this list? I poked around in the netsh help info but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Have you reordered the bindings? In Network Connections press alt to get the tool bar to come up, select advanced, and reorder the adapters to the one you want listed first

Comment: Interestingly enough, despite netsh ordering my interfaces as above, when I tried this approach my interfaces were already listed in the order I want. I tried switching them, saving, and then switching them back, and (whether that was the reason) my machine's FQDN is now resolving to the interface I want. However, resolving the machine name alone is still resolving the other interface. Maybe this is NetBIOS? I don't know much about that though, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want your server to register DNS with only one of the NICs go into Network connections / properties of the adapter you don't want registered in DNS / TCP/IP4 / advanced / DNS tab / uncheck the option to register this connections address in DNS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the network connection access order

`In Network Connections press alt to get the tool bar to come up / select advanced / reorder the adapters to the one you want listed first`

To change which adapters register with DNS

`Network connections / properties of the adapter you don't want registered in DNS / TCP/IP4 / advanced / DNS tab / uncheck the option to register this connections address in DNS`

Comment: The second part here in particular did the trick. Removed the other interface from DNS, rebooted, problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it's me, but I've been 20 years in IT/Windows, and I don't get your question...    It has 2 different interfaces, which have different security groups applied?  Whitelist some machine addresses ?

Resolving is done by DNS. DNS services are provided by a server which has an IP address.  If your Windows machine is multi-homed and has multiple possible paths to that one IP address, something is wrong, not ?!   Or is this an AWS thing ? (no experience with that)

Comment: Sorry, the "security groups" on them are an AWS-specific construct that abstracts a firewall. I added that information to provide background on why I have two interfaces, and why I prefer one over the other when resolving the FQDN on my domain.

Comment: If you need clarification of the OP's question, post a comment under the question. Don't ask for additional information in answers.